# differences not shown while browsing the code

Tags: github

The following page shows the difference with 2 versions correctly as expected.

https://github.com/shantanuo/mobileapp/commit/52e98f297df7944e10cdefd9951d199a4b070bf4#diff-1c08dde01f1c9c4f327ba6b5279d9baa

But the next version fails to show the differences.

https://github.com/shantanuo/mobileapp/commit/185b6231c491a5a580595a816be82e50449f3d06#diff-1c08dde01f1c9c4f327ba6b5279d9baa

I will like to see the color-coded line differences. Is there any way I can commit the changes differently to get that screen as shown in the first link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It says "1 additions, 111 deletions not shown". And the wikipedia_data.sql is not text file.
When request the raw data: https://raw.github.com/shantanuo/mobileapp/185b6231c491a5a580595a816be82e50449f3d06/wikipedia_data.sql

It give the `Error: blob is too big`

So, github cann't show the diff.

Comment: But it shows the differences correctly for the same file for different commit. This is a plain text file.

Comment: @shantanuo But the size of file is 22953.025 kb...So maybe the diff is too large to display ?